# Frequent Windows 7 Blue Screens

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, bios

My computer was all bought in October 09 and assembled by myself. I haven't had any problems until I moved from North Carolina to New York.

Now, I've been getting blue screens such as `PAGE_FAULT_IN_NON_PAGED_AREA`, `IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL`, and `BAD_POOL_HEADER`. Sometimes while on it just browsing the internet or something, the screen will just glitch up like a broken NES and reboot.

[image]

After I get a BSOD, I can't even boot into BIOS and I have to try for about an hour to even boot up.

I've checked my CPU and MB temps and they're both pretty average.

## CPU SPECS:

[Case + PSU](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811148047)
[Motherboard](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131398)
[Memory](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820227346)
[CPU](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819103704)
[Wireless](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000UOC3QK)

Answer (score 2):

These errors generally point to faulty hardware, RAM in particular.
From [Microsoft's Technet Article on this error](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957625.aspx).

> This Stop message usually occurs after
>   the installation of faulty hardware or
>   in the event of failure of installed
>   hardware (usually related to defective
>   RAM, either main memory, L2 RAM cache,
>   or video RAM)

Since this has all happened after a major move and given that you built this yourself I'd look at just stripping out as much as you can and making sure everything is seated properly and no dust\debris has gotten stuck in somewhere unwelcome. It could actually be a genuine failure but in most cases like this it will just be something that has come loose.

Comment: Yes, I've unhooked my secondary HDD, wireless card, and DVD-RW. I'm going to attempt to boot up and run a memtest.

Answer (score 1):

Check all cable/card connections in your computer and do a full harrdisk/memory test. This sounds like something broke during the move.

Comment: I agree, I'm going to preform a memtest as soon as I get home again.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem that was traced back to graphic card.

After removing it from AGP slot, vacuum-cleaning the slot and putting card back in, everything went to normal.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the video is onboard.

Comment: It may be some other card in your case - if you have any. Or, in worst case scenario, it could be problem with motherboard connections.